# Not able to connect to MongoDB with Terminal

Tags: database, mongodb, terminal, command, mongo-shell

for some reason I'm not able to connect to my MongoDB Atlas Database using my Terminal.
Here is what I have done so far:

- created brand-new MongoDB Account
- created new Cluster (Shared)
- created Database Access with Admin privileges
- created Network Access for every IP-Adress
- created a new Database within the Cluster

Then I was ready to try it out in the Terminal.
I followed the instructions you get after pressing connect on the Atlas DB.
I entered the following command:

```
mongosh "mongodb+srv://cluster0.us7i2.mongodb.net/FIRST" --username admin --password myPassword
```

"FIRST" is the name of my database and "admin" the name of my Database Access.

After entering the command I get this:

```
Current Mongosh Log ID: 619377ee69f496969e5c7168
Connecting to:          mongodb+srv://cluster0.us7i2.mongodb.net/FIRST
```

And then nothing happens...
Am I connected now?
In tutorials I saw that you are supposed to enter DB commands now.
How am I able to use the database?
I have mongosh version 1.1.2 if it has something to do with it...

Thank you!

Comment: if you write "mongo" in terminal and press ENTER can you acess to mongo shell?

Comment: Test with `nslookup -q=srv _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.us7i2.mongodb.net` and `nslookup -q=txt cluster0.us7i2.mongodb.net` to make sure the DNS changes are visible to your terminal.

Comment: This seems to narrow down the problem. I'm not able to reach the server. ";; connection timed out; no servers could be reached". Do you have any idea how I could move forward?

Comment: Some ISPs and DNS providers don't support SRV.  Try getting the pre-3.6 connection string from Atlas.